# Unable to have border-bottom for th and border-top for td under th at the same time

Tags: html, css

Is this some known issue or what.

My code is like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <th>Something</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Something else</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The trouble is that I am unable to set

```
tr th { border-bottom: 1px solid red; }
```

and at the same time

```
tr td { border-top: 1px solid green; }
```

It is not working. Only the th red line is shown.

Is this a bug or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry..what you are trying to do is that you are placing one border on another border..so that's why only first one is showing.